# how do I call the function from the upper class? the class is not inherited

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

```
class a{

private:
        class b* b = new b;
        int getSomeWhatValue(){
              
        }
};

class b{
private:
        void bFunc(){
               //I want to call an getsomewhatvalue() here
        }
};
```

I made the code really simply. How do I call an a's function at b? I tried to use `this`pointer, but didn't work :(

Comment: It is not possible, since ```class b``` does not know anything about ```class a```. I'd suggest to reconsider the design of your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario will cause a cyclic calling (i.e. never ending loop of A creating an instance of B which in tern creates an instance of A and the loop continues), so its not permissible.

You have two options:

1. Declare "int getSomeWhatValue()" as static, and call it through the class (instead through an instance).
2. Pass a pointer to the function you want to call (int getSomeWhatValue()) and delcare the prototype somewhere outside of class A or B.

Comment: Do you mean to use this pointer in option 2? I tried to give  `this` pointer of a to b when I created it, but didn't work. Could you explain more about option 2?

Comment: I don't see an endless loop... the desired call to `getSomeWhatValue()` appears to be in a member function of `b`, not its constructor. (It still doesn't seem lie the correct thing to _want_ to do, though).

Comment: No, You would need to provide a pointer to a function prototype